# Case insensitive search doesn't work on Django (Postgres) with non-latin characters

Tags: python, django, postgresql

PostgreSQL 13.4
Django 3.2
MacOS 11.2

I try to implement a search function for finding a model instance by the "name" field.

*models.py*

```py
    class LatestConfiguration(models.Model):

        # Primary key
        name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Имя',
                                max_length=150,
                                unique=True,
                                primary_key=True)
```

Database encoding is UTF8:

```
➜  ~ psql <DB_NAME> -c 'SHOW SERVER_ENCODING'
 server_encoding 
-----------------
 UTF8
(1 row)
```

Database contains records, eg:

```
Бухгалтерия для Казахстана, редакция 3.0
```

I try to search a model instance like that:

```py
 LatestConfiguration.objects.filter(name__icontains='Бух')
```

the output is ok:

```
>>> LatestConfiguration.objects.filter(name__icontains='Бух')
<QuerySet [Бухгалтерия для Казахстана, редакция 3.0]>
```

I lower-cased the first letter in 'Бух' to 'бух' and repeated the search

```
>>> LatestConfiguration.objects.filter(name__icontains='бух')
<QuerySet []>
```

so now I get an empty queryset but I shouldn't

I also tried Q-objects:

```
Q(name__istartswith='бух')
```

but didn't get any results

Tried to use postgres full text search
by adding:

```
    'django.contrib.postgres',
```

to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py

and repeated searching this way:

```
>>> LatestConfiguration.objects.filter(name__icontains='бух')
<QuerySet []>
```

Anyone else got the same error?

Comment: What is the *collation* of you database?

Comment: show lc_collate; C

Comment: show lc_ctype; C

Comment: seems like I need to recreate my database cluster using en_US.UTF8 collation :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I looked at all system locales
by executing

```
locale -a
```

I had no required locale ru_RU.UTF-8
so I made it by

```
locale-gen ru_RU.UTF-8
```

Restarted postgres to make it see a new locale

```
service postgresql restart
```

logged in as an admin

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

and created a new DB like that

```
CREATE DATABASE "<Mydatabasename>" WITH ENCODING 'UTF8' LC_COLLATE='ru_RU.UTF-8' LC_CTYPE='ru_RU.UTF-8' TEMPLATE=template0;
```